# How do you create another unique user id in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Im building an app that will have multiple users that are going to be sharing data with about 3-5 other users. So I will need to assign each user to a unique group ID so that they will only be able to access the data associated with their groups. What is the best way to generate unique group ID/keys that can be shared among 3-5 different users.

Comment: There are lots of ways out there to generate a unique ID.  Search for UUID.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `push().getKey()` to get the unique key.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String key = database.getReference("quiz").push().getKey();
```